# Hack to change the webpage of a website?

Tags: attacks, exploit, xss, attack-prevention

Recently, there is a website by Malaysia Airline got hacked and their main page has been defaced, below is a link to that article

http://techcrunch.com/2015/01/25/malaysia-airlines-site-hacked-by-lizard-squad/

I want to know how did the hacker change the html file?

Do they attack in the DNS server, and reroute the request to that website to another server? How do they do all this?

The second question, I would like to ask is how do I protect my site from these kinds of attacks?

I want to know how they did it, so I could improve on my web security

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the fact that the hackers had access to the servers and their data, then they had direct access to the HTML files.

Protection against such an attack is very broad in scope, because you have to protect yourself against all forms of intrusion into your network.

Comment: so you mean, to defaced the webpage - the only possible way is to login into their server and change their html file? and this attack could have started months ahead to get access to the server? no other way to change html besides accessing to their server?

Comment: That isn't what I'm saying. I'm saying that for THIS attack, the attackers had complete access to the backend. As for how one could deface a random web page, there are many, many ways to do that.

Comment: oh ok! i got it! ;) thanks! do you mind share some ways to deface? so i know how to find information about them?

Comment: SQLi, RFI, XSS, server config errors, brute forcing the ssh/ftp logins. There are too many methods to mention.